# An Update Javascript problem with increments

Tags: javascript, json, database, puppeteer, user-registration

So I solved my last issue with the help of another user, but the other issue Im having with the code :

```
const faker = require('faker');
const userList = require('./users.json')
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var obj={
    'table':[]
  };

 for (i=0; i <10 ; i++){
   let username = faker.internet.userName();
   let password = faker.internet.password();
   obj.table.push({"id":i,name:username,pass: password});
 }
 jsonfile.writeFile('users.json', obj, {spaces:2}, function(err){
   console.log(err);
 });

 console.log(userList.table);
```

If I use the command :

```
console.log(userList.table[0].name);
console.log(userList.table[0].pass);
```

That prints out the password fine, but my next step is I want to use the data which I will do by using .type(then the user+ pass) once It has automatically typed those, what would I have to use to either go to the next line so [1] automatically, or remove is it easier to remove it and then place it inside of a new JSON file.

Im using this to test signing up to a website.

1. Go to website wait for selector
2. enter user and pass generated from faker.
3. take user and pass generated from faker and store it elsewhere.
4. move onto next user and pass
   and repeat.

Hoping someone can help,

many thanks!

Comment: So you are using the same data for input and check in the backend and want to go through the data line per line?

Comment: Yes so the User + Pass is generated into the JSON. I then take the first user and pass, enter it and then transfer it into a different JSON file

Answer (score 0):

My main question here is, why you are depending on JSON files, or if you could do it simple with the existing variable.

If you continue from this point you can just loop over the table array and take every user dataset for the input.

```js
const logins = {
  table: []
};

userList.table.forEach(async (user) => {
  const userName = user.name;
  const passWord = user.pass;

  // Just guessing how you load the page
  await loadPageAndWaitOnSelector();

  userSelector.type(userName);
  passSelector.type(passWord);

  // Now you'll can check if the login was succesful and save it
  await loginSuccessFull();

  logins.table.push(user);

  // Write the data after each login to a new file
  jsonfile.writeFile('logins.json', logins, {spaces:2}, function(err){
     console.log(err);
  });
})
```

In the end you'll have to json files with the same content. But if you
want to check which logins where successfull, you'll have to add an additional if condition around the saving part.

#### In memory solution

You could combine your part with the above on the generate the faker data on the fly.

```js
const faker = require('faker');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

/**
 * This generates a tuple with username and password
 */
const generateUserLogin = () => ({
  userName: faker.internet.userName(),
  passWord: faker.internet.password()
})

/**
 * A reducer function which test the login and saves the data 
 * as success or as failure
 */
const loadPageAndLogin = async (logins, credentials) => {
  // This is needed to get the previous function call finished
  const acc = await logins;

  // Destructuring the tuple into variables
  const {userName, passWord} = credentials;

  // Just guessing how you load the page
  await loadPageAndWaitOnSelector();

  userSelector.type(userName);
  passSelector.type(passWord);

  // Now you'll can check if the login was successful
  const isSuccess = await loginSuccessFull();

  if (isSuccess) {
    acc.success.push(credentials);
  } else {
    acc.failure.push(credentials);
  }

  return acc;
}

// Creating an empty array with 10 entries
const logins = [...Array(10)]
  // generate a login for each entry
  .map(generateUserLogin)
  // test the page with each generated login
  .reduce(loadPageAndLogin, Promise.resolve({success: [], failure: []}))

// Write the data after to a new file
jsonfile.writeFile('logins.json', logins, {spaces:2}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

In this example, only a json file for the result is generated. In it you'll have the success and failure logins separated.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. Isn’t JSON the best? I’m going to a login page via puppeteer I then want it to take the pregenerated user and pass, enter it and then past those two in a new file so I know which ones have gone through

Comment: I don’t question the JSON format, but if you only need the generated data there is no need to save it to a file.

Comment: I realise what you mean now, yes So is the code above good for using the generation and then saving the successful one to the JSON so I know where its signed in

Comment: Just to update. Instead I am using Firebase now, which seems to be working better